# Android - What is the correct way of using this GPS Tracker function?

Tags: java, android

Im tring to get the longtitude and lattitude. I have this function in MainActivity

```
private double[] getGPS() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

Location l = null;

for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
    if (l != null) break;
}

double[] gps = new double[2];
if (l != null) {
    gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
    gps[1] = l.getLongitude();

}
return gps;
}
```

However, when I am using it as

```
Toast.makeText(this, "" + getGPS() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In onCreate, It gives me strange characters like DE[R@F. What is te correct way to use my function to get the longtitude and lattitude correctly ?

Comment: Maybe `Arrays.toString(getGPS())`?

Comment: @mike returns always 0,0

Answer (score 1):

> In onCreate, It gives me strange characters like DE[R@F

You are printing the object identifier of a `double[]`.

> What is te correct way to use my function to get the longtitude and lattitude correctly ?

Access the two elements of the array individually.

> returns always 0,0

`getLastKnownLocation()` usually returns `null`. Use `getLastKnownLocation()` **only as an optimization**. Use `requestLocationUpdates()` to request that the device attempt to locate the device.